# Counting Boolean Values in field of Child Model in Django QuerySet API

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following model (*below*).

I would like a query that returns every record of parent `Question(models.Model)`, where ALL the values for the `is_relevant` field within the child `Choice(models.Model)` are "True".

Having a difficult time creating the `QuerySet`.  Any Assistance would be very helpful.

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)



class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    is_relevant = models.BooleanField()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reverse relationship of the `Question` model like so:

```
Question.objects.filter(choice__is_relevant=True)
```

The `choice` in `choice__is_relevant` is the lowercase name of the model `Choice`.

Reference: [Relationship lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)